# Navbar with two images left and right and a search field in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm creating a navbar with Bootstrap. I would like to have two images left and right and a search field in the center. The navbar should have the height of the two images. The search field should be located both horizontally and vertically in the center of the navbar. This is my current code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="../images/Image1.png" width="280" height="80" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche" name="suche">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <img src="../images/Image2.jpg" width="330" height="80" alt="">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-form{
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

Can I do that more skillfully? Especially the thing of locating the search field in the center horizontally and vertically?

Comment: you are probably better off using bootstrap 4 - it uses flex and has classes for vertical and horizontal aligning

Comment: Quick demo bootply - couldn't find the vertical align class that applied to flex but you get the idea: http://www.bootply.com/VW55SeJYnJ

Comment: the reason why your search field is not centred is because you are using col-sm-4 class and  give inline-style to your img tag width="330px"

Answer (score 1):

This very easy do through flex-box

```css
.navbar {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="img">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="submit" value="Ok">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: who vote this solution up? this solution is not working for Bootstrap architecture!!! and it is bad hack!

Comment: @MKAD I'm really looking forward to your decision of this question